# MATLAB is not working because of Java

Tags: windows-7, java, matlab, jre

I use Windows 7 x64. I have installed MATLAB 2010a to my computer. After running only the splash screen shows up for a while then program quits. I have found an error log and the first lines of the file says:

> An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
>
> EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000778008c5, pid=2156, tid=2656
>
> Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (11.2-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64)
>    Problematic frame:
>    C  [ntdll.dll+0x508c5]
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>      http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp

I am not sure if I am right place to ask this. I have changed my visual styles to windows classic.

I have tried to run MATLAB with `-nojvm` parameter. Only command window showed on the screen. Then I enter `desktop` command. but it did not accepted my command. It says:

> Desktop is not supported because Java is not currently available.

As far as I have researched it is Java problem. I have uninstalled JRE 7u45 and then installed JRE 6u45x64. Nothing has changed.

Comment: What is the required version of the JRE that Matlab 2010a uses? If you don't know, then contact Matlab, and update the question with the supplied information.

Comment: Matlab comes with its own Java (AFAIK). It is possible that your installation of the JRE made Matlab's own somehow inaccessible. A possible solution would therefore be to uninstall the system JRE.

Comment: This honestly sounds like a problem with MATLAB and not Java itself. Have you tried reinstalling MATLAB as well?

Comment: @A.Donda I have unistalled all java stuff. Then reinstalled MATLAB. It did not run either.

Comment: Sorry, then I don't have an idea. I recommend that you contact TMW support.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the macafee virus protection software was blocking java (although matlab did eventually load after thinking about it for literally over 20 minutes).

Try adding matlab or java to your whitelist. I'd love to hear from anyone else with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

From [Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/10388)

Try going to C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R20.. and deleting all .xml settings files. Then delete your log file and re-run MATLAB.

Comment: Ihave alredy deleted it a fes times. No help.